# Identity Server 4 .Net Logout

Tags: .net, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

There are multiple applications using same Identity Server, Profile Service is hit each time we open a different application. 1 application has different User Table and other have different. 
So when I logged in to one app and then also with other the other application does not have the user details.

What I simply want is to Logout Identity Server if User detail are null.
This is the ProfileService:

public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {

```
    var userIdString = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
    var accountId = context.Subject.FindFirst(item => item.Type == "accountId").Value;
    if (userIdString != null)
    {
        var userId = int.Parse(userIdString);
        if (context.Client.ClientId == "App1")
        {
            var user = _userProvider.GetUserById(userId, _validationContainer, context.Client.ClientId);
            if (user != null)
            {
                context.IssuedClaims = new List<Claim>    {
               new Claim("username", user.Username),
           new Claim("userId", user.UserId.ToString())
               };
            }
            else
            {
             // HERE I want to LOG OUT 
                return null;
            }
        }
        else if (context.Client.ClientId != "App2" && context.Client.ClientId != "App3")
        {
            var user = _userProvider.GetUserById(userId, _validationContainer);
           if(user!=null){
            context.IssuedClaims = new List<Claim>
                {
               new Claim("username", user.Username),
           new Claim("roleId", user.RoleId.ToString()),
           new Claim("userId", user.UserId.ToString()),
           new Claim("customerId", user.CustomerId?.ToString()??""),
           new Claim("accountId", user.AccountId?.ToString()??""),
           new Claim("userAccountId", user.UserAccountId?.ToString()??"")
               };
     }
              else{
            // LOG OUT HERE
             return null;
             }
        }
        else
        {
            var user = _userProvider.GetEPMUserById(userId, accountId, _validationContainer);
            if (user != null)
            {
                      context.IssuedClaims = new List<Claim>
              {
                    new Claim("username", user.Username),
                  new Claim("roleId", user.RoleId.ToString()),
                  new Claim("userId", user.UserId.ToString()),
                  new Claim("customerId", user.CustomerId?.ToString()??""),
                  new Claim("accountId", accountId),
                  new Claim("customerName", user.CustomerName),
                  new Claim("userAccountId", accountId),
                  new Claim("customerRoleName", user.RoleName),
                  new Claim("reportuser", "admin")
              };
            }
            else
            {
                // HERE I want to LOG OUT 
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

How can I log out here in Profile Service or any other scenario.

Comment: The ProfileService is called when the client accesses the UserInfo endpoint. It's just a request for an id_token, so you can't logout in the ProfileService. Second of all, IdentityServer is not a membership system. Once authenticated, any user can use any client. So despite having seperate user tables, this does not bind a user to one app. IdentityServer is an implementation of oidc: one user that can use any client without having to login (single sign-on (SSO).

Comment: Please note that IdentityServer takes care of User authentication and Client/resource authorization. User authorization is not part of IdentityServer. So don't set user authorization in IdentityServer, but instead use an implementation (as recommended) of the (local) [PolicyServer](https://policyserver.io/).

Comment: But I want it to be forcefully logout as user does not belong to that product,

Comment: It's up to the _client_ to determine whether the user is authorized and deny access if not. You can use middleware to shortcut the pipeline in case the user is not authorized. Take a look at the [Sample OSS version of PolicyServer](https://github.com/policyserver/policyserver.local) to see how you can implement this middleware.